# SQL error trying to convert varchar to decimal

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the following error. Why is it trying to convert to an int when I'm trying to tell it to convert to a decimal?

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '938.00' to data type int.

Here is the business end. If I filter out the period, it does work but I need that period for when I import the data into Excel.

```
convert(decimal(9,2),'"+$WorkSheet.Range('D13').Text.replace("'","").replace(" ","").replace("$","").replace(",","").replace("-","")+"'+0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because you are using `+ 0`, which means that `+` is treated as addition rather than concatenation.  I think  simple solution would be replace:

```
replace('convert(decimal(9,2), @val)',
        '@val',
        $WorkSheet.Range('D13').Text.replace("'", "").replace(" ", "").replace("$", "").replace(",", "").replace("-", "")
       )
```

Comment: Ok thank you I'll work on that. I thought that might have something to do with it. The reason the +0 is there is if the varchar is empty it complains because it can't convert that to a decimal either.

Comment: @Zach . . . You will need other logic.  The replacement needs to occur before the value is put into the SQL expression, using `coalesce()`, `case`, or some equivalent.

Comment: @Zach . . . I don't know.  That sounds like an Excel/Powershell question.

Comment: I mean with stackoverflow. If I use shift enter to put things on a new line, it doesn't show up as a new line in the comment.

Comment: @Zach . . . If you put four spaces at the beginning of a line, it will be treated as code and line breaks are respected.  If you put two new  lines, then the second starts a new paragraph.

Comment: Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It is gnarly looking, but seems to work. Testing will continue. Thanks again.

```
convert(decimal(9,2), ISNULL(NULLIF('"+$WorkSheet.Range('D14').Text.replace("'","").replace(" ","").replace("$","").replace(",","").replace("-","")+"', ''),'0')),
```